# Pain in lower inward part of my feet during long run (and certain type of shoes)

Tags: long-distance-running

It's strange because it only occurs in my left feet.  There is a strong bruise and slight pain to start with. If I keep running it turns into a hell.

It gets recovered in day or two of rest.

I have taken the wet test and both my feet are normal in terms of arch. Hence I have taken a neutral shoes (Hoka One One Clifton 3).

Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: Can you actually see a bruise? Or is it bruise like pain? When you say lower inward do you mean in your arch?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't diagnose your pain, only guess. Please see a medical proessional in person.

Answer (score 1):

> **PLEASE NOTE:**  This is by **NO MEANS** a clinical diagnosis. Any advice received **ANYWHERE** online should **NEVER** be taken as such.
>  **ALWAYS** consult a medical professional in your area.

Based on the information given it sounds like a Tarsal Bone Stress Fracture.

As you did not indicate location it's hard to rule out other probable causes. However the most common I see in patients involve the Navicular (which is a tarsal bone or foot bone).  If you haven't already please consult your physician.

**Navicular Stress Fracture**

- A navicular stress fracture is one of the most common stress
  fractures affecting athletes, especially those in explosive events
  such as sprinting and jumping.

**Navicular Stress Fracture Symptoms**

Symptoms of a navicular stress fracture include

- Poorly localized ache with bruising in the midfoot area, which gets worse with exercise.
- Pain may radiate along the inside arch of the foot and is minimized at rest only to return again as training resumes.
- Tenderness may be felt when the thumb is pressed into the top of the 
  foot over the navicular bone, called the N spot.

**Navicular Stress Fracture Explained**

- The navicular is one of the tarsal bones in the ankle. It sits on top
  of the calcaneus or heel bone. A stress fracture of the navicular is
  caused by over use or repetitive strain, usually from high impact
  sports such as sprinting, hurdling and jumping.
- Poor technique or    training errors can also contribute to the
  likelihood of sustaining a    stress fracture of the foot.
- The navicular bone gets pinched or impinged between the bones to the
  front and back of it causing it to be compressed.

An X-ray may or may not show the appearance of a stress fracture therefore a bone scan or MRI is of more use.

Comment: No xray, no exam, nothing. I hope this diagnosis doesn't cause complications if you are wrong.

Comment: John please note by NO means is this an official diagnosis and should NEVER be taken as such. You will need to see a medical professional in your area that not only has your medical background but also the ability to perform hands on testing, palpation etc. I am giving a ONE possible hypothesis based on the limited information that has been given.

Comment: Yes. You are peering through a scope, darkly, and giving a medical opinion. If the OP elects to act upon that, I sincerely hope that you were correct. It is for that reason that we mark things like this as off topic, both here and on the Health.SE site.